# How can I benchmark a websocket-based Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, benchmarking, websocket, socket.io

I am testing the scalability of a websockets application I wrote using socket.io and Node.js. I want to stress test and benchmark the performance. What are some tools I can use?

So far I've looked into [wsbench](https://github.com/pgriess/wsbench) but I'd like to explore any alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a very simple [Socket.IO client implementation](https://github.com/stephank/Socket.io-node-client) for Node.js. It's not an actual benchmarking tool, but it does know about Socket.IO's protocol.

Using that, it's fairly easy to write a client that interacts with your application.

Comment: I've been trying to do this on and off for the last few days and there are serious problems with this approach. It's fine for low numbers of concurrent connections, but for connection counts over a few hundred it starts to fall apart. I may be doing something stupid, but connections start failing silently when they receive messages too frequently. This doesn't happen at low concurrency, only at high concurrency. Whatever the reason, it makes actual serious load testing nigh impossible. Is this a problem with my app? Have you had success with high concurrency?

Comment: @Drewww just wondering how you ended up going with this, I found some of your code at https://github.com/drewww/socket.io-benchmarking and noticed it appears you implemented the client in python?

Comment: The python implementation didn't work very well either. The only way I got it to work at serious scale (> 1k concurrency) was to use Java. The python attempt is still in that repo, but it didn't ever really work effectively.

Comment: @drewww Have a look at my answer on this post, spent the day playing around with benchmarking socket.io and got 60,000 connections easily, however I wasn't testing messages between client and server. Just general overhead with the heartbeats.

Answer (score 11):

Spent the day looking into benchmarking node.js and socket.io, I tried a number of solutions, I found you can't use [wsbench](https://github.com/pgriess/wsbench) to benchmark socket.io because socket.io has its own protocol that needs to be addressed to make the connections.

After trying a few other solutions with no luck I ended up using [socket.io-benchmark](https://github.com/michetti/socket.io-benchmark) and I just hit 60,000 connections on a m1.large EC2 instance using only one core with room to spare. In my case I only wanted to measure the overhead of the socket.io connections (which required me to comment out some code in socket.io-benchmark) so I didn't have any messages sent between client and server.

It was interesting to see the clients took more CPU and Memory than the server. So make sure the client server you're benchmarking from is beefy, I used a EC2 c1.xlarge and had plenty of head room. And I broke the benchmark into 6 individual processes so it could scale across the multiple cores and avoid memory limits.

Be careful to set the `<rampup in seconds>` option high enough on the clients, if you set it to low everything buffers and grinds to halt.

The only problem with socket.io-benchmark is I had to use node v0.4.12 to get it all working due to a dependency on v8-profiler which won't compile under newer versions of node (as of writing).

Answer (score 5):

https://www.npmjs.org/package/thor

It a commandline utility and has similar output as Apache Bench

```
Thor:                                                  version: 1.0.0

God of Thunder, son of Odin and smasher of WebSockets!

Thou shall:
- Spawn 1 workers.
- Create 2 concurrent/parallel connections.
- Smash 100 connections with the mighty MjÃ¶lnir.

The answers you seek shall be yours, once I claim what is mine.

Connecting to ws://server:8080/examples/websocket/chat

  Opened 100 connections


Online               439 milliseconds
Time taken           441 milliseconds
Connected            100
Disconnected         0
Failed               55
Total transferred    132.62kB
Total received       71.85kB

Durations (ms):

                     min     mean     stddev  median max
Handshaking          1       5             3       4 20
Latency              0       0             1       0 3

Percentile (ms):

                      50%     66%     75%     80%     90%     95%     98%     98%    100%
Handshaking          4       5       5       6       7       11      17      20      20
Latency              0       0       1       1       1       1       1       2       3
```

Comment: I was using Thor recently to do some load testing and discovered that Thor doesn't actually open concurrent connections. They close shortly after being opened. (I discovered this using the HAProxy stats screen.)

Answer (score 0):

For just benchmarking of how many concurrent connections can be set up I'd recommend [wsbench](https://github.com/pgriess/wsbench/). However it will not work for Socket.IO sites (because more complicated handshake). I was researching it and found a couple of tools that just set up connections to Socket.IO server. It's not enough for measuring real performance. 
What you need is to send and receive real messages that simulate real client of your web application. I've described some ideas on how to create your own benchmark here: [Benchmarking for Node.JS / Socket.IO sites](http://blog.sphereinc.com/2012/04/benchmarking-for-node-js-socket-io-sites/)